# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection in mvc5 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to do a loop in mvc5 view for particular model properties but I'm getting an error:

> Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed
> and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

This is the view I have:

```
@using App.Models
@model App.Portal.WebUI.Models.ManageViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.Id)
                <label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AUser.Id)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.Email)
            </div>
        </div>
       
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
            @foreach (AspNetRole userRole in Model.AUser.AspNetRoles)
            {
                    @Html.CheckBox(userRole.Name, true)
                    @Html.Label(userRole.Name)<br />
            }
    </div>
</div>
```

The error happens in the foreach loop.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

### Update

Code added:

```
ManageViewModel model = new ManageViewModel();

            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                using (var db = new DbContext())
                {
                    AspNetUser user = (from p in db.AspNetUsers
                                       where p.Id == id
                                       select p).First();
                    model.AUser = user;

                    List<AspNetRole> roles = (from r in db.AspNetRoles
                        select r).ToList();

                    model.RoleList = roles;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't recommend using database connections (i.e. your `ObjectContext) or performing any 'heavy' operations from within your view pages as this is a violation of MVC design. Your View-Model should be completely populated and completely disconnected from external resources when passed to your View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @foreach (AspNetRole userRole in Model.RoleList)
            {
                    @Html.CheckBox(userRole.Name, true)
                    @Html.Label(userRole.Name)<br />
            }
```

Don't use Entities connected to the DB in your ViewModel! NEVER!! It causes issues like you have just encountered. Separate layers. Read about separation of concerns [separation of concerns](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/introduction-to-mvc-architecture-and-separation-of-concerns/)

Comment: I want to iterate through the roles for the user.

Comment: AspNetUser user = AspNetUsers.Where(user => user.Id == id)
                    .Include(user => user.AspNetRoles)
                    .First();

Comment: Thanks @free4ride. Now what are my options to display both all the roles and check the roles the user has using both the user roles and the roles which exists from the model? Thanks again, I selected your answer as correct

Comment: sth like this:
@foreach (AspNetRole role in Model.RoleList)
{
    @Html.CheckBox(role.Name, Model.AUser.AspNetRoles.Any(userRole => userRole.id == role.Id))
    @Html.Label(role.Name)<br />
}

Answer (score 2):

My guess without seeing how you populate the Model class, is that the query for `AspNetRoles` has not actually been executed yet, and is doing so when you start iterating over the list with the `foreach`. The db context has been disposed in the controller, and so can no longer fetch the list results at that point.

When you populate the Model data in the controller, try doing `.ToList()` at the end of the query where you populate AspNetRoles, which will execute the query immediately. Hope this helps!